# How to disable color transition in highcharts gauge-solid

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Gauge-Solid Chart from 0 to 200 percent.
if the number i get out of my code is higher than 100% the chart should be just green and under 100% just red. But theres always this transition so when the number is like 90% or 110% the chart is always brown if i do it like this:

```
yAxis: {
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickPixelInterval: 400,
                tickPositions: [0, 200],
                tickWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    y: -70
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                stops: [
                    [0, '#C80000'],
                    [1.0, '#088A08']
                ],
            },
```

Comment: You can change your stops a little bit. Please check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3z20vza/ You can also use another type of colors code, so it will not make this transition http://jsfiddle.net/o3z20vza/1/

Answer (score 1):

Replace stops with this:

```
stops: [
           [0.999999, 'green'], //green
           [1.0, 'red'] // red
       ]
```

Comment: This answer unfortunately does not solve the question ... it only shows red when the value of y is 100% of its maximum value. The original poster wanted a different, solid color when the gauge was >= 100 out of a maximum value of 200.